# Command is running different from expected when i use it trought Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, cmd, ffmpeg

I have a code where i download a youtube video as 3gpp and convert it to a mp3, i need to use FFmpeg to do this, and it work well when using both cmd and powershell, but, when i tried to run the same command in Python, it didin't work at all.

**This is my command:**

`ffmpeg -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3`

**I tried:**

`subprocess.call(r'%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ffmpeg -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3', shell=True)`

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg","-i","C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp","C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3]")
```

```
os.system('powershell ffmpeg -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3')
```

```
subprocess.run([
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.3gpp"),
    os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.mp3")
])
```

```
subprocess.call('C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe ffmpeg -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3', shell=True)
```

all of them return some type of error, in some of them it returns that ffmpeg isn't a recognized as a internal command, in others it says that the system can't find the specified path, but none of them works, even thought it works perfectly when i use the exactly same command on cmd/powershell.

sorry for my bad english :3

Comment: Watch the wrong position of the last quotation mark in `subprocess.run(["ffmpeg","-i","C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp","C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3]")`, it must appear *before* the closing bracket…

Answer (score 1):

All of the commands should work (with some fixing)...

You may try the following:

1. Add `-y` argument for overwriting the output file without asking.
   When executing from Python you might not see the question:
   `File 'C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N]`
   Example for adding `-y`:

   ```
   subprocess.call(r'%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ffmpeg -y -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3', shell=True)
   ```
2. Make sure `ffmpeg.exe` is in the system path.
   In case you are not sure if `ffmpeg.exe` is in the system path, try using full path.
   Assume for example that `ffmpeg.exe` is in `c:\FFmpeg\bin\`, use full path:

   ```
   subprocess.call(r'%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3', shell=True)
   ```
3. Use `r""` prefix, or use double the backslash:
   Replace `os.system('powershell c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3')` with:

   ```
   os.system(r'powershell c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3') 
   #or: os.system('powershell c:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg -y -i C:\\YTDownloads\\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\\YTDownloads\\CurrentAudio.mp3')
   ```

---

Replace `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.3gpp"), os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.mp3")])` with:

```
parent_dir = r'C:\YTDownloads'
newname = 'CurrentAudio'

subprocess.run([
    r'c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg', '-y',
    '-i', os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.3gpp"),
    os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{newname}.mp3")
])
```

---

Replace `subprocess.call('C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe ffmpeg -i  C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3', shell=True)` with:

```
subprocess.call(r'c:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -y -i C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.3gpp C:\YTDownloads\CurrentAudio.mp3')
```

There is no need to use `powershell` and no need to use `shell=True`.

---

Notes:

- The examples assume that `ffmpeg.exe` is in `c:\FFmpeg\bin` folder.
  You may copy `ffmpeg.exe` to `c:\FFmpeg\bin`, or use the actual folder of `ffmpeg.exe`.
- You may also add the folder that contains `ffmpeg.exe` to the system path as described in the following [guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows).

Comment: Thanks! it worked! i guess there is some problem with my path environment, cause ffmpeg is actually in there, but i'll use this way for now, thanks, really, you helped a lot